# How to calculate this residue which has a pole of order n-r?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

So I have this complex integral:
$$ \oint \frac{dz}{2\pi}\frac{e^{iz(br-(n-r)a)}}{\left(1-(1-q)e^{-ik_{1}-iza}\right)^{n-r}}$$
b,r,q,a,n are all constants in this context.

However I'm not entirely sure what the best way of calculating the residues is?

So far I have that the pole must satisfy $(1-q)e^{-ik_{1}-iza}=1$, which means that $z=\frac{1}{a}(-i\ln(1-q)-k_{1})$. I know that this pole is of order $n-r$ so the formula to calculate the residue is:
$$\frac{1}{(n-r-1)!}\frac{d^{(n-r-1)}}{dz^{(n-r-1)}}\left\{\left[z-\frac{1}{a}(-i\ln(1-q)-k_{1})\right]^{n-r}\frac{e^{iz(br-(n-r)a)}}{\left(1-(1-q)e^{-ik_{1}-iza}\right)^{n-r}}\right\}$$

However I can't seem to use this formula to the calculate the residue. Is there a better way of doing it? Or am I just not seeing something obvious? Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: To even start talking about poles, you need to describe your contour for which you're integrating along.

Comment: Woops. It's a circular contour of radius R centred around 0. The integral is being used to calculate it's corresponding definite real integral so I want to use the standard Cauchy Residue Theorem on it.

Comment: So the next thing you need to do is make sure where the function has a pole is even inside your circle, otherwise you can't apply the the residue theorem. You can also always look at the coefficient of $c_{-1}$ in the Laurent series to ding the corresponding residue, granted $R$ is big enough so that the pole is inside your contour.